# Método JavaScript no se ejecuta

Tags: javascript, html5

Buen día, tengo un problema en javascript con un botón

```js
var frutas = ["bananas", "pera", "naranja"]
document.getElementById("lol").innerHTML = frutas

function myfun() {
  frutas.push("lemon")
  document.getElementById("lol").innerHTML = frutas
}
```

```html
<h2>Practica </h2>
<br>
<button onclick="myfun">aprieta</button>
<p id="lol"></p>
```

Sucede que cada vez que lo ejecutó da error no se si sera error de sintaxis o algo que esté obsoleto si me ayudan

Comment: Agrega el mensaje de error que obtienes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

el problema esta en que llamas erroneamente a la función de javascript, te falta poner onclick="myfun()" como esta a continuación:

```js
    var frutas = ["bananas", "pera","naranja"]
        document.getElementById("lol").innerHTML = frutas

        function myfun(){
            frutas.push("lemon")
            document.getElementById("lol").innerHTML = frutas
        }
```

```html
<h2>Practica </h2>
<br>
<button onclick="myfun()">aprieta</button>
<p id="lol"></p>
```

Comment: muchas gracias  @connie r.m.